# I need help trying to get the sum of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, sum

```js
var nestedArr3 = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6]]];

function sumTotal() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < nestedArr3.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < nestedArr3[i].length; j++) {
      if (typeof nestedArr3[i][j] === "number") {
        sum += nestedArr3[i][j];
      } else if (Array.isArray(nestedArr3[i][j] === true)) {
        sumTotal(nestedArr3[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return console.log(sum);
}

console.log(sumTotal());
```

I am getting a result of 0. I can't figure out how to fix this code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Jiajie Xu**, do not do like that if you're using **recursion** to get the **sum** using this code. I have made changes to it to make it working. Please have a look.

> Always make sure to write a **reusable** function that's why here it's taking 1 parameter as an array.
>
> I have used **filter()** method to get the sum of array elements. Check
>   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp for details.

```
function sumTotal(nestedArr3) {
    sum = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < nestedArr3.length; i++) {
        if(typeof nestedArr3[i] === "number"){
            return nestedArr3.reduce((num1, num2) => num1 + num2);
        } else 

        if(Array.isArray(nestedArr3[i]) === true){
            sum += sumTotal(nestedArr3[i]);
        }            
    }
    return sum
}

// TEST
var nestedArr3 = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6]]];

console.log(sumTotal(nestedArr3)) // 21
```

Answer (score 5):

Some issues:

- If you're going to try for a recursive solution, best to only try to recurse *one* element deep before calling `sumTotal` again, else you have repeated (WET) code
- When using recursion, you need to `return` the result at the end so the caller can access the result
- `Array.isArray(nestedArr3[i][j] === true))` looks like a typo - move the `true` *outside* of the `Array.isArray` call

Here's the working code:

```js
var nestedArr3=[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6]]]

function sumTotal(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] === "number") {
      sum += arr[i];
    } else if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      sum += sumTotal(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumTotal(nestedArr3));
```

But it would be a lot cleaner with `reduce` instead, assuming all elements and sub-elements will be either numbers or arrays:

```js
var nestedArr3=[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6, [[100, 100, [100]]] ]]]
const sumTotal = (arr) => arr.reduce(
  (a, element) => a + (
    typeof element === 'number' ? element : sumTotal(element)
  ),
  0
);
console.log(sumTotal(nestedArr3));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to flatten your array. I use this function from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
function flattenDeep(arr1) {
   return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
}
```

From there, you can just use reduce

```
var result = flattenDeep(nestedArr3).reduce((a,c) => a+c);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it with just for loops, you were missing an extra dimension from you array. The solution should be something like this:

```
function total(array) {
var sum = 0

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < array[i][j].length; k++) {
        if (typeof array[i][j][k] === 'number') {
          sum += array[i][j][k]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return sum
}

console.log(total([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6]]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

use [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to flatten the array then sum it using [.reduce() :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var nestedArr3 = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6]]];

var sum = nestedArr3.join().split(',').reduce((total, curr) => {
  return total + +curr // +curr is shorthand for parseInt
}, 0)

console.log(sum);
```